# Show blue location dot in Baidu Maps on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, baidu-map

I have an app that has been using Google maps and I want to add Baidu maps. I have added Baidu maps and can get the map to show up and centred on the user's current location but I can't get the blue location dot to show.

Does anybody know how to do this?

App with Google Maps:

[image: App with Google Maps]

App with Baidu Maps:

[image: App with Baidu Maps]

Comment: If you want that blue mark in google maps, yourMapView.myLocationEnabled = true

Comment: I have it in Google Maps. I need to get it showing in Baidu Maps.

Comment: Search Baidu Maps documentation for current location enabling options.

Comment: I have searched thoroughly but haven't been able to figure it out. I wouldn't have posted the question without extensively researching it first. I was hoping to find someone here who had implemented it for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Baidu documentation says

```
/ / The following mapView for the BMKMapView object / / display positioning layer 
mapView.showsUserLocation = true; / / set the positioning status to the normal positioning mode 
mapView.userTrackingMode = BMKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading;
```

Did you try any of these?
you can get it with gogle translation: http://lbsyun.baidu.com/index.php?title=iossdk/guide/create-map/location

and read that: http://lbsyun.baidu.com/index.php?title=ios-locsdk
You need to apply for a key to use positioning

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You need the key to get the maps to show at all. I have the maps showing and centring on the users location, it is just the blue location dot I can't get working. I had mapView.showsUserLocation = true in my code but hadn't played around with userTrackingMode. I have put that in now and still can't get it to work.